# domain.in/wp-admin give the result to 403 Access to this resource on the server is denied!

Tags: htaccess

I'm new to wordpress.
I installed wordpress in my domain. It shows the theme, But When I type 
`http://domain.in/wp-admin`

It's redirecting to 403 page with message `"Access to this resource on the server is denied!"`

If I install the wordpress in `http://domain.in/test/`. It allowing me to login in the admin panel and works fine. I don't want to give another `/folder`. I want to install in the root directory only.

can any one suggest me what i have to do.

I tried the `.htaccess` with

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

But no use and i gave `0777` permissions to all the files and the directories.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you visit /wp-login.php ? Is the .htaccess itself set with proper permissions? My wp-content, wp-admin, and wp-includes all have `rwxr-xr-x / 0755` and my wp-login.php, .htaccess all are `rw-r--r-- / 0644`

Is this a fresh install? You can also check the server logs and the last resort, but perhaps the easiest, contact your host and have them take a look at root permissions and config.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. @Jarmerson, I don't know what exactly happen, I installed it freshly, have found the above issue, so I contacted my host provider the resolved it.
Thank you for Anser

Comment: No problem. The last comment in my answer was to contact your host and have them see what needs to be done. If they were able to direct you and solve the issue, I'm glad my answer was helpful. If you have a moment, consider accepting my answer and that it was useful. Thanks!